# Open chrome browser with Selenium in VBA

Tags: excel, selenium-chromedriver, vba

I've downloaded Selenium to automate some web browsing in VBA, and as excited as I am to use it, I cannot seem to get it up and running.  I'm trying to open up a chrome browser to start navigating to pages and doing what I need to do but every time it opens up to a blank page with URL "data:," and I get an error "WebRequestError   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a receive."

I've seen several tips for this type of thing searching around but in trying to implement them I've still not cleared anything up.

Things I've tried:

- Downloaded SeleniumBasic-2.0.9.0
- Downloaded Chromedriver 2.40
- I think I'm supposed to put the chromedriver somewhere so I have it in the same folder as SeleniumBasic but I'm not sure if that's right.

I'd really like to get this up and running so I can play around with Selenium and get some automation going and I feel like this part should not be this hard so if I could get some help on getting past this stupid little barrier I would really appreciate it.

Comment: what is the process for putting the driver on the environmentals path, I think that may be the problem.  Chrome is up to date for me.

Comment: how do i know what path to write out? and should i replace info.txt with chromedriver.exe?  I know next to nothing about command prompt so specificity here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: ok i don't want to keep asking the same question and seem like a TOTAL moron but how do I know what path to set for the chromedriver?

Comment: alright here we go, i think we're almost there.  what do i do now that i know that its not in the path when i type echo %PATH%

Comment: oi thanks for all the help, it was going smoothly until i set up the path and now it's just telling me that chromedriver is an "Unsupported 16-Bit Application"... any tips?

Comment: The info I have found so far on unsupported 16-bit error are out of my knowledge area. I would suggest you try two things. Uninstall and re-install driver with re-start of computer once you have put on path. If error still occurs, contact a support forum/line e.g. Microsoft and see what they advise. Sorry I can't help more on this.

Comment: ended it up getting it to work late in the workday yesterday.  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: How did you fix it? And welcome to selenium basic!

Comment: I guess I had to paste the new chromedriver into the location of the one that comes with SeleniumBasic bc SeleniumBasic is a little older and the chromedriver is updated more often.  It was probably the last piece of a multiple piece puzzle.  Regardless, good to be able to move forward.