# Why is my VBA code unable to select "Download" in order to download a .xls file this specific website?

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I am wondering why my code does not work on this site in particular. I would like to be able to have it press "Download" in order to initiate the process for downloading an .xls file. However, it does not and I am unable to figure it out.

```
Public IE As InternetExplorer

Public Sub Main()
  Call InitiateIE
  IE.navigate ("https://www.auction.com/event/details/E-11142/?filter=reset")
  Call LoadIE
  IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button-root_button_jzfF button-role-default_button_3iu5 button-is-medium_button_3vqd navigation-btn_styles_M1TS download-inventory-btn_styles_3ytA navigation-container-element_styles_3MZ0")(0).Click
  Call LoadIE
  IE.Quit
End Sub

Private Sub InitiateIE()
  Set IE = New InternetExplorer
  IE.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub LoadIE(Optional BufferTime As Long = 1000)
  Do While IE.Busy
  Loop
  Do Until IE.Document.ReadyState = "complete" Or IE.Document.ReadyState = "interactive"
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you run your code step by step using F8 and stop after line `IE.Document…` and have a quick look at the Internet Explorer window there is a red popup for about 2 seconds saying *"Event Details - We're having a technical problem. Please try again in a few minutes."*

Comment: Got it. I just spoke with the Auction.com technical team and they have disabled interactions using IE and only work on Google Chrome.

Comment: Unrelated: You should never write `Do While <something>; Loop` with nothing inside it because that will cause 100% usage of one CPU core for no good reason and make the application unresponsive as well. Put a `DoEvents` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an aside I would go with an attribute = value CSS selector btw

```
ie.document.querySelector("[data-elm-id='event_details_download_auction_inventory']").Click
```

---

**Selenium Basic with Chrome:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDownload()
'VBE > Tools > References > Selenium Type Library
'Requires latest chrome browser and chrome driver
'Chrome driver containing folder must be on environmental path
'Download selenium https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.auction.com/event/details/E-11142/?filter=reset"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        .FindElementByCss("[data-elm-id='event_details_download_auction_inventory']").Click
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

[Other selenium info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52690693/6241235)

[Environmental path](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) - the driver must sit in a folder which is on this path.

Comment: Got it. I just spoke with the Auction.com technical team and they have disabled interactions using IE and only work on Google Chrome.

Comment: That's ok. You want a chrome answer? Assuming you can install selenium basic.

Comment: And if you can't install selenium I could probably write you something in python/java which could be run from command line an IDE.

Comment: Hello QHarr, Thank you for your offer. However, I would like to learn how to use Selenium first! I don't want your efforts to go to waste. I have downloaded Selenium and am now looking into how to set it on PATH. Many thanks!

Comment: No worries. Let me know if any problems. There is a tutorial [here](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) and remember to look at the example.xlsm on [Github](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/tree/master/Examples/Excel)  You can additionally pass the path to the driver folder as an argument to selenium.

Comment: Okay. So I was able to run it but the following came up: Run-time error '33': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Comment: oh.. on which line? I tested it and it ran fine.

Comment: WAIT. I looked at a previous comment of yours on another post and a user stated that they just had to paste the new driver into the SeleniumBasic folder.

Comment: you could try that. Mine is on the environmental path. Did the other user pass that path to selenium as an argument/was the selenium folder on the environmental path?

Comment: Here is the link to the thread! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196363/open-chrome-browser-with-selenium-in-vba